# Actionable Message "autoInvokeAction" disappears from card body when received in outlook

Tags: outlook-web-addins, adaptive-cards, office365-apps, office365connectors

When I send an actionable message containing a card with "autoInvokeAction", it doesn't appear in the message in Outlook. It just comes through set to null.

However, the confusing thing is that when I send the **exact same card JSON** using the site https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/, it **does** appear in the body.

Why would my outgoing email be treated differently from the AMDesigner?

Comment: Just make sure that you use the latest Outlook build and see still if you can repro the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer today by getting in touch with Microsoft Support. The actionable messages team has to approve the sender for the auto-invoke capability. It doesn't work by default. This isn't documented.

Comment: Makes sense tho...could be easily abused.